# Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building [Spring boot project]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a problem. I got SSL exception constantly. I did configure these things:

1. Already added cert file into java cacerts
2. Already added SSL config on my Spring boot project

but I got SSL exception when I attempt to call external API from spring boot project.

> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building
> failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
> unable to find valid certification path to requested target Apr 02
> 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) Apr 02
> 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:324) Apr
> 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267) Apr
> 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:262) Apr
> 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
> Apr 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
> Apr 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
> Apr 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:377) Apr 02
> 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
> Apr 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:422)
> Apr 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
> Apr 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:149) Apr 02
> 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1143) Apr 02
> 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1054)
> Apr 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:394)
> Apr 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
> Apr 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
> Apr 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1340)
> Apr 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1315)
> Apr 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:264)
> Apr 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:104)
> Apr 02 10:04:44 dbx-gauli java[13294]: ... 124 more Apr 02 10:04:44
> java[13294]: Caused by:
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target Apr 02 10:04:44
> java[13294]: at
> sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:456)
> Apr 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:323)
> Apr 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:271) Apr 02
> 10:04:44  java[13294]: at
> sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:315)
> Apr 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:223)
> Apr 02 10:04:44  java[13294]: at
> sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
> Apr 02 10:04:44  java[13294]: at
> sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
> Apr 02 10:04:44  java[13294]: ... 140 more Apr 02 10:04:44
> java[13294]: Caused by:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target Apr 02 10:04:44
> java[13294]: at
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
> Apr 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
> Apr 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) Apr
> 02 10:04:44 java[13294]: at
> sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:451)

My Java config looks like that:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

// set up a TrustManager that trusts everything
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    System.out.println("getAcceptedIssuers =============");
                    return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                            String authType) {
                    System.out.println("checkClientTrusted =============");
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                            String authType) {
                    System.out.println("checkServerTrusted =============");
            }
} }, new SecureRandom());

SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext);
Scheme httpsScheme = new Scheme("https", 443, sf);
SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
schemeRegistry.register(httpsScheme);
```